# R inner join different data types

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, left-join

I was wondering if there was a way or maybe another package that uses SQL queries to manipulate dataframes so that I don't necessarily have to convert numerical variables to strings/characters.

```
input_key <- c(9061,8680,1546,5376,9550,9909,3853,3732,9209)
output_data <- data.frame(input_key)

answer_product <- c("Water", "Bread",   "Soda", "Chips", "Chicken",     "Cheese",   "Chocolate",    "Donuts",   "Juice")
answer_data <- data.frame(cbind(input_key, answer_product), stringsAsFactors     = FALSE)

left_join(output_data,answer_data, by = "input_key")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `left_join` function from `dplyr` work also with numerical value as key.

I think that you problem come from the 'cbind' function, because its output is a matrix those can only store one kind of data type. In your case, the numeric values are casted to char.
In contrary of `matrix`, `data.frame` could store different type of data, like a list.

Form your code, the key column is converted to char:

```
> str(answer_data)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ input_key     : chr  "9061" "8680" "1546" "5376" ...
 $ answer_product: chr  "Water" "Bread" "Soda" "Chips" ...
```

If instead you construct the data.frame with:

```
answer_data_2 <- data.frame(
  input_key = input_key,
  answer_product = answer_product,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
```

the key colunm stay numeric

```
> str(answer_data_2)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ input_key     : num  9061 8680 1546 5376 9550 ...
 $ answer_product: chr  "Water" "Bread" "Soda" "Chips" ...
```

and

```
left_join(output_data,answer_data, by = "input_key")
```

work with the numerical keys